# Errors in single file - Windev

Tags: windev

While occurring fatal errors application shows an error message and we can copy that. Is there anyway to write all the errors in a file to trace issue occurs in customer application. This will helpful for trace the issues from customer side.

Expecting Replies

Thank you

Shijo S Philip

Answer (score 0):

```
WHEN EXCEPTION IN
//put your code here
DO
MyErrorMessage is string=ExceptionInfo()
END
```